# Sequel Pro Fails to Connect to MySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, ssh, virtualbox

In my case Sequel Pro is reporting:

`Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Which is strange because I am able to connect via ssh and then use the mysql command.  I am connecting to a virtualbox guest machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved this but couldn't find it documented anywhere so I am posting this to help others:

I had "AllowTcpForwarding no" in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Once I updated the value to "AllowTcpForwarding yes" and restarted the ssh server with `sudo restart ssh` SequelPro was then able to connect to the mysql server (after hours of failed attempts).

Hope this helps someone.